# Android:Display Long text in single line in autocomplete textview with cursor at start position

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to display long text in `autocompletetextview` in single line.

I am able to place text in single line but when I select text from drop down cursor points to end location of text.

I want the cursor to point to start of `autocompletetextview` box after i select one from dropdown list. Right now cursor is end of the autocompletetextview box.

This is my `autocompletetextview`

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/myautocomplete_pickup"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"

    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:dropDownHeight="200dp"

    android:hint="Pick Location"

/>
```

Can anyone please help me...?

Comment: what do you mean by first location of text?

Comment: also I want to know, why you have added "android:" without any attribute and value ?

Comment: Even i have the same issue can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

first for single line set "android:singleLine="true""in autocomplete view,
to bring the cursor to front set text in setOnItemClickListener

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this with this code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/materialAutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Eventos"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**